# wordpress : identify user way to an item

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-taxonomy

is it possible to track the route that the user took to get to a page ?

say that i have a post that have 2 different taxonomies
taxonomy 1 = make
taxonomy 2 = color

i want to create a different layout for each route

**this is my current hierarchy:**

```
Mercedes -> blue     -> car - the user gets template 1 (single-car.php)
blue     -> Mercedes -> car - the user gets template 1 (single-car.php)
```

**this is what i want**

```
Mercedes -> blue     -> car - the user will get template 1 (single-car_by_make.php)
blue     -> Mercedes -> car - the user will get template 2 (single-car_by_color.php)
```

is that possible without using extra query-strings ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not writing actual code. But I just giving idea how to do it.

use the the following logic in the your single-car.php file

if(taxonomy == make )
get_template_part( 'single-car_by_make' );

if(taxonomy == color) 
get_template_part( 'single-car_by_color' );

I hope It will help you.